# NLog doesn't print value from aspnet request header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog, request-headers, ilogger

I'm having some trouble getting NLog to print the value from a specific request header - the `x-correlation-id` header being assigned at the beginning of a request. Actually I can't get NLog to print any headers at all.

In my `nlog.config` I have the following layout and target. The guid contained in the `x-correlation-id` header should be printed right after the loglevel.

```
<variable name="layout" value="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${aspnet-request-headers:HeaderNames=x-correlation-id:ValuesOnly=true} | ${logger}.${aspnet-mvc-action}() | Msg: ${message}${when:when=length('${exception}')>0:Inner= | }${exception:format=tostring}" />
<targets>
  <target name="logfile" 
          xsi:type="File"
          fileName="${logDirectory}\${shortdate}_logfile.txt"
          layout="${layout}"/>
</targets>
```

Example output from log file:

```
2020-05-27 16:29:07.1991 | INFO |  | KrFo.KlientServices.Skelet.Logic.HelloWorldService.GetHelloWorld() | Msg: Hello from controller.
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit 1:**
I have now looked further into this issue. And as @RolfKristensen mentions I have turned on the internal NLog log. I am seeing this specific line in there:

```
2020-05-28 22:43:42.4260 Debug Missing serviceProvider, so no HttpContext
```

From what I understand, this service provider is passing the `HttpContext` to NLog so ofcourse it doesn't print anything from the `HttpContext`. I just can't seem to find any solution to this. Google doesn't help me much on this.

---

**Edit 2**:
Ok. So apparently this happens due to the time the `x-correlation-id` header gets applied to the request in relation to when I'm trying to access the header in my NLog layout. Not sure how this works and why, but it's the only explanation I can see. I found out that I am able to print all current request headers by calling `${aspnet-request-headers}` in my NLog layout. But still couldn't print the `x-correlation-id` header (because it was not yet applied).

Fortunately I found a great work around in the CorrelationId service initialization. By adding the CorrelationId to the logging scope in the `ConfigureServices()` of `Startup.cs` like

```
services.AddDefaultCorrelationId(options => options.AddToLoggingScope = true);
```

I am able to fetch the CorrelationId from the logging scope and print it to my layout by calling the item name "CorrelationId" (default) on the NLog [Mapped Diagnostic Logical Context (MDLC)](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Mdlc-Layout-Renderer) like `${mdlc:CorrelationId}`

This doesn't answer my original question. But it gave me a work around and I am now able to print the CorrelationId to my logfile on every request.

```
2020-05-29 17:24:26.2250 | INFO | 6d7d8d8a-eca4-4af5-81d4-beb11d7f2766 | KrFo.KlientServices.Skelet.Logic.HelloWorldService.GetHelloWorld() | Message: Getting list of HelloWorlds
```

Comment: Always a good idea to check the NLog InternalLogger for warnings, when having issue with output: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: Most of the time there is something wrong in the setup of NLog, as there the httpcontext etc are connected to NLog. Double check https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3#4-update-programcs (or the ones for ASP.NET Core 2 or 1)

Comment: If correlationid is important, then `${aspnet-traceidentifier}` might do the trick. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetTraceIdentifier-Layout-Renderer